# What is the proper term for real oil vs. flavoured oil?

Tags: oil, language

Is there a better term for flavoured oil?

For example, a "chili oil" is clearly not same as "grape seed oil" or "snake oil".

Comment: 'snake oil' is a flavored oil ... or might not have any oil at all.  It's some sort of tonic that's claims to do something miraculous but doesn't.

Comment: I've seen infused oil as a term for flavored, but it might not be the only or overarching term

Comment: Apparently (Wikipedia) the original snake oil is actually made from snakes. It is fat extracted from the Chinese water snake. It is used as an alternative medicine and not for cooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chilli oil has at least touched chillies (or chilli extract). [Pizza oil](https://www.coopathome.ch/en/supermarket/food-cupboard/vinegars-oils/oil/speciality-oils/lesieur-pizza-oil/p/3851376) on the other hand is neither made from pressed pizzas nor flavoured with pizza extract.

English isn't logical. French isn't either, but at least it would use *Huile de pépins de raisin*, *huile (aromatisée) au piment fort* (or more commonly *huile pimentée* or *huile piquant*) and *huile pour pizza*, i.e. oil *of*, *(flavoured) with*, or  *for* something.

Comment: Ah, pizza oil is really marketing, like they sell same broad chemical as many brands by all poisonable insects.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's all about marketing and "tradition."

The "Chili oil" could be rewritten as "Chili flavored oil", and in the ingredient list, the oil type should be written (olive oil, grape seed, peanut, ...)

"Grape seed oil" is just oil made from grape seed.